# How can I set monero-wallet-rpc default password

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, password-confirmation

I want to set a permanent `monero-wallet-rpc` password.

Right now every time I run `monero-wallet-rpc` I am asked to define a password.

How can I make this password be **permanent**?

Comment: I’m also interested in this question

Answer (score 0):

You can start the wallet RPC with either of these flags:

```
--password arg                    Wallet password (escape/quote as needed)
--password-file arg               Wallet password file
```

You then won't be prompted to enter a password.